# How do I reset/restore an icon in the start menu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, menu, icons

I have an entry for the web browser Firefox in my start/favorites/kicker/KDE menu which has no icon. All other entries are OK. The text reads "Web Browser" and, smaller and gray, "Firefox Web Browser".  I looked in Favorites, search and App/INet

How do I restore the Firefox icon?

Comment: @enzotib he's using KDE, no gnome-panel

Comment: Aaron, does FF have an icon under the Applications/Internet menu?

Comment: @Dirk: Nope, no icon anywhere. I looked in Favorites, search and App/INet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. right click on the KDE icon in the bottom left corner (Kickoff Application Launcher) and choose `Edit Applications`
2. select the entry for FireFox and click on the icon area to the right of the Name field to pick a new icon for the menu entry
3. you should be able to choose a FireFox icon in the dialogue that opens up, or browse to a location where you have one

Comment: Thanks, that works mostly. After saving the changes, the icon was still missing in "Favorites" but after removing the entry and adding it again, the icon showed up. Thanks.